# Move working copy of SVN repository

Tags: linux, svn

I want to move my working copy of an SVN repository from /usr to /home
Can I just move the repository using mv or is there something else that needs to be done?

The same goes for deleting a working copy of a repository, if I wanted to delete my working copy could I just go ahead and delete it or is there some administration that needs to be done first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a working copy on your computer you can always move it somehere and it still points to the svn location. Check that location with the "svn info" command (will show you the URL to where the local copy points to). If you want to relocate your svn repository, that's a different problem.

If you delete a working copy you don't lose your repository data, just your local working copy of it.

Regards

Comment: Just make sure you don't have any pending changes that aren't checked in before you delete. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The main thing to watch out for is whether you've got any relative paths referring to things outside the working tree in files that *aren't* under version control. (I'm not sure if this can happen when you `./configure` or not.)